# Source control: projects which share a 3rd library which is still under development in RTC

Tags: .net, version-control, ibm

this is not a new question for source control, but IBM's Rational Team Concert is a slightly different animal than Git, SVN, etc.

We have a number of .NET web sites under development with Visual Studio.  Each web site is represented by a VS solution.  They all share in common a .NET library, also under development.

Is there a smart way to set up in RTC so that each web site's repository does not contain its own copy of the common library's source?  My first thought was to just set the library up with its own repo in RTC, then have each "child" web site solution refer to the common library in sandbox.  But I'm new to RTC and not so sure this is the most RTC-ish way, or what trouble I'll encounter later.  Thoughts?  Thanks for any light shed.

Comment: Why do you need the source in each web site repository?

Comment: Is (an answer to) this question still relevant to you?